# Icons on second monitor positioned above the screen on second monitor UBUNTU 17.10

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, 17.10

I have two monitors connected by an hdmi cable, one has 1920*1080 resolution and the second one has 1366*768 resolution.

I have my bigger monitor as my main display, and unfortunately the icons on the second screen are located above the screen. as can be seen here:

[image]

Also, when I open stuff like the Files program, the program launches above the screen size, so I can't close it or move it around..

Can you please help me fix that problem? it didn't happened on UBUNTU 17.04.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: After spending the last 24 hours trying to recover from my 17.04 -> 17.10 upgrade, I was headed to AskUbuntu to post my question which is almost identical.  My notebook screen is 1366x768 while my hdmi-connected display is 1920x1080.  Under 17.04, my external screen was my primary with my laptop was secondary.  With 17.10, windows open on my primary monitor with their window controls inaccessible.

Comment: @TheGeeko61 I get you man, this is so frustrating, thank you for your respond though:)

Answer (score 0):

While we await a definitive answer, I've been exploring possible answers.  I was able to resolve the issue by logging out and logging back in using ***X*** instead of *Wayland*.

If using *Wayland* is a requirement, then the best result is obtained thusly:

[USING WAYLAND]
I had a very similar result until I adjusted the external monitor's dimensions to more closely match those of the built-in monitor.  I did this using the GUI sequence:

> (1)`<right-click> on the display`
>
> (2)`choose Display Settings`.

I adjusted the resolution of my external monitor from **1920x1080** to **1360x768**.  Now that the vertical resolution of both monitors is 768, all works as expected.  Hope this helps.

I vaguely recall having done the same thing when I first set up my dual-monitor solution under 17.04. So, I think it's the case that the 17.04 -> 17.10 upgrade process failed to retain those earlier settings.

If you're more of a command-line user, then `gnome-control-center display` is the command that will enable you to adjust the resolution of your display.

Comment: First, thank you very much for trying to help, I really appreciate that :) Second, Having a lower resolution on a monitor, is not a solution, it's just an alternative, but it's pretty hard to get used to it. Third, On the resolution menu I don't have even one similar option to choose on both monitors, everything is different (on one monitor I have 1024*768, 960*720, and so on. and on the other one I have totally different options..) , so I can't have the same vertical/horizontal resolution on both screens..

Comment: It's not simply that I was trying to help you; I was trying to help ME!  :)  You're right; when I first began addressing my problem, I also was presented with options far apart from one another (as you're pointing out).  However, those options appear to be fluid, based upon discovery with successive restarts.

Have you examined your ~/.config/monitors.xml file?  If memory serves me correctly, removing that file causes gnome to rebuild it.  Try that.

Comment: I can change the resolution from there, you are correct. but as I said, I probably won't do it, but at least you tried:)